# Generically checking for null that won't box nullables on a non-constrained type.

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say I have the following method:

```
public static int CountNonNullMembers<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    if (enumerable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerable");
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var x in enumerable)
    {
        if (x != null) count++; 
    }
    return count;
}
```

And I have these 3 arrays::

```
var ints = Enumerable.Range(0,10).ToArray();
var nullableInts = Array.ConvertAll(ints,x=>x as int?);
var strings = Array.ConvertAll(ints,x => x.ToString());
```

I wrote a little function to do a loop and time it for a million iterations. Applying it to `ints` and `strings`, it finishes in about 100 ms on my machine. For `nullableInts`, it takes 2.5 seconds. 
As I understand the check for null on `int` doesn't make sense, so the compiler has a different template for non-nullable `struct` types, that removes null checks. But `Nullable<T>` does not have a template that converts the null check to `x.HasValue`. If I have an unconstrained function, how can I do a null check that will perform well? I can't use `EqualityComparer<T>`, as null might not be a member of `T` as there is no constraint.

Also it's impossible to have overloads that differ by constraint, so I can't, say, have one for `structs`, one for `Nullable<T>`, and one for classes.

The caller of the method is non-constrained. This is just an example (not the actual method); the method calling is non-constrained. I need to do some work against non-null members, and it's a generic method. I suppose I could write a version that doesn't do the check vs one that does (and consequently has a different signature), but it's seems very ugly and unneeded.

Also, the extension method `.Count` inexplicably performs horribly for `NullableInts` and `strings`, (equally bad), so it really isn't the right approach. This might be the delegate invocation, but I doubt it. Using the `UnboxT` style method of `Check<T>.IfNull` performs a lot better. 
Okay, really weird switching the body of the count to this performs great:

```
    public static int CountNonNullMembers<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        return enumerable.Count(Check<T>.IfNull.Invoke);
    }
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `UnboxT` approach works. But I'd also like something that doesn't require creating a static type::

```
public static class Check<T>
{
            public static readonly Predicate<T> IfNull = CreateIfNullDelegate();
            private static bool AlwaysFalse(T obj)
            {
                return false;
            }

            private static bool ForRefType(T obj)
            {
                return object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null);
            }

            private static bool ForNullable<Tu>(Tu? obj) where Tu:struct
            {
                return !obj.HasValue;
            }
            private static Predicate<T> CreateIfNullDelegate()
            {
                if (!typeof(T).IsValueType)
                    return ForRefType;
                else
                {
                    Type underlying;
                    if ((underlying = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T))) != null)
                    {
                        return Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                            typeof(Predicate<T>),
                            typeof(Check<T>)
                                .GetMethod("ForNullable",BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
                                    .MakeGenericMethod(underlying)
                        ) as Predicate<T>;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return AlwaysFalse;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Using this approach everything performs about the same. `Strings` performs worse, but not so much worse than everything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can [constrain generic type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to reference types or values types:

```
public static int CountNonNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    where T : class
{
    return source.Count(x => x != null);
}

public static int CountNonNull<T>(this IEnumerable<Nullable<T>> source)
    where T : struct
{
    return source.Count(x => x.HasValue);
}
```

You don't need an overload for non-nullable structs, because they can't be null anyway.

Comment: This doesn't work as the call site is non-constrained. This is just an example (not the actual method) the method calling is non-constrained.

Answer (score 0):

While not necessarily better than your method, it doesn't require a whole class:

```
static Dictionary<Type, object> NullChecks = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
public static Func<T, bool> MakeNullCheck<T>()
{
    object obj;
    Func<T, bool> func;
    if (NullChecks.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out obj))
        return (Func<T, bool>)obj;
    if (typeof(T).IsClass)
        func = x => x != null;
    else if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        func = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.Property(param, typeof(T).GetProperty("HasValue")), param).Compile();
    }
    else
        func = x => false;
    NullChecks[typeof(T)] = func;
    return func;
}
```

Comment: The point was to do this in a way that performs. `OfType<T>` requires casting and doing an if check its really quite bad.

Comment: How badly does `OfType` perform?

Comment: Michael: I see your problem now. It's not that the null check is slow, it's that the `int?` values keep getting boxed.